# Windows 7 - Lost internet connection suddenly, Can ping but no browsing

Tags: windows-7, internet

I was working with internet like usual, Suddenly it stopped browsing websites. I can ping but browsing doesn't work.

OS : Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, System type : PC

Internet Connection : The PC gets it's connectivity through the laptop. In other words I am sharing my laptops wireless using a ethernet cable with my pc.

Comment: Have you tried a trace to see where it drops the connection?

Comment: And is it more than one browser that fails?

Comment: @Wulfhart Question Updated. Not sure what's wrong with trace route.

Comment: How is the PC sharing its wireless connection? Bridging? ICS?

Comment: I was going to suggest a problem with your DNS server and specify a public one but you tracert-ed by hostname... maybe look for Browser Helper Objects?

Comment: The machine that has the issue is getting internet via a laptop?  Are you able to try a direct connection to eliminate the laptop as the source of the issue?

Comment: @Psycogeek Question Updated. I realy have no idea if this is a virus doing or corrupted drivers, misconfigured network. Last thing I remember doing was Installing the flash player update. And the moment the internet starts disconnecting was when I was downloading Diablo 3 through it's client. It seems it has a P2P transfer option. Maybe a virus was downloaded through that ?

Comment: @Psycogeek I am not sure what you mean by "Put address in a list" or "Hardcoded". I tried ping many domain names, tried pinging IP address, tried setting DNS manually, disable and enabling in device manager. I do get reply. One weird thing is that, I can ssh to my vps server which is located in France. So this means I am connected, right ?

Comment: Every indication you have given so far is that you have number resolutions , so yes, them numbers the computer understands are going through and comming back.  your connected, the gateway is functioning, the local addresses are configured.

Comment: @Psycogeek I can't believe this, I can even connect to my VPN too! What's going on :-O Thanks for explaining Hardcoded. I got what you mean. I did try pinging some IP addresses too. I can get reply from anywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you should do to fix this problem: ( Special Thanks to [Psycogeek](https://superuser.com/users/98855/psycogeek) )

1. Install MalwareBytes, Update, Do a full system scan.
2. Install Microsoft Security Essential, Update and a full system scan.
3. If you have any Norton AV product, Uninstall it using `Norton Removal Tool`. There is a high possibility that it might block web traffic.
4. Open cmd and run `sfc /scannow`
5. Update your network adapter drivers
6. Enable Telnet client (Google it if you don't know how), open cmd and run `telnet www.google.com 80`. Check the output and see if you can connect to it or not. If there is no message at output there is a possibility that you have problem with cables or hardware components.
7. Try to ping some domain names you never have visited before. And ping some IP address directly. If you can't get reply you probably have DNS problems. You can also give DNS address manually in your adapter settings. Don't forget `ipconfig /flushdns`
8. Keep enabling/disabling network adapters, rebooting system and using "Diagnosis" feature of windows while doing all these tests.
9. Try to run `netsh winsock reset` and `netsh interface ipv4 reset` and `netsh interface ipv6 reset` in cmd. Make sure to reboot to see effects.
10. Undo any registry tweaks you have done before to your network  interfaces.
11. Download `TCP Optimizer` latest version, Run it and choose your network interface and speed. Click either Windows default/Optimal setting and apply it. Be sure to tick the registry backup. Reboot and see changed
12. Check your browser proxy settings. Make sure you are not using a global proxy and try to see if you can reach web using different browsers. don't stick to one.
13. Make sure Netbios is enabled in  your network adapter settings.
14. Try to disable anything other than `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/Ipv4)` in your adapter setting to see if something is wrong configured.
15. If you are on a DHCP network, check if `Obtain DNS Address Automatically` is ticked.
16. Go into safe mode with networking to check if you can reach web in there. Or try another user. It might be caused by a specific user.
17. Use CCleaner to check all startup items and disable unnecessary items. Some services or programs can cause this, report says one of them is `Bonjour Service`
18. Open Run, execute `services.msc` and check if all network-related services are running.
19. Open browser and check if you can open a https website ? This problem might be caused on a specific protocol like http or port 80.
20. If you have a HUB switch like mine, Try to swap ports. It helped in my case. Check if cables are not cut.
21. This also can be caused by some kind of worm or malware which is undetectable by any AV product. So try to check your process running in task manager, analyze eachone and try to end process those suspicious exe files.
22. Check your HOSTS file located in `windows/system32/drivers/etc/` It might be you're pointing all domains to localhost.
23. Check the 13 Network adapter items in Device manager, for disabled or failing Driver/service items. Different ones are needed for different connection types.

Comment: That's a pretty awesome answer to your own question, less than a day later.

Comment: CCleaner reports a lot of fakes in order for you to buy their product, I don't know why people so highly recommend it.

Comment: @Deza Well I didn't said to use it for registry clean-up. I mentioned it for checking on startup items and maybe to clean up temporary files. And as I know the program is free. The paid version should be more likely a donate app. Btw, What registry cleaner you believe is trustworthy and accurate ?

Comment: Not CCleaner, all you have mentioned can be accomplished on windows without any additional tools.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my machine somehow or another decided it needed to connect via a proxy on all my network connections, including special VPN's...  I had previously ran all of the netsh commands, the ipconfig commands and checked my host file, but as soon as I unchecked proxy's for all devices, it worked.

I have ZERO idea how those got checked, and to be honest it kind of concerns me.

unchecking proxy fixed my connection problems.